# I need to print the specific part of a line in a txt file

Tags: python

I have this text file that reads ,,Janitors, 3,, ,,Programers, 4,, and ,,Secretaries, 1,, and all of these are on different lines. I need to print out Janitor seperate from the number 3, and this has to work for basicaly any word and number combo. This is the code I came up with and, of course, it doesnt work. It says ,,substring not found,,

```
File = open("Jobs.txt", "r")
Beg_line = 1
for lines in File:
    Line = str(File.readline(Beg_line))
    Line = Line.strip('\n')
    print(Line[0: Line.index(',')])
    Beg_line = Beg_line + 1
File.close()
```

Comment: This looks like a problem regexes could solve, if you provide a short example of the file we might be able to come up with something for you

Comment: Without the correct file content, it is not easy to answer straight about it. because your question itself needs some more rephrasing for more clarity. Better to provide the file sample to understand it better also needs some rephrasing too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the following code:

```
file = open("Jobs.txt", "r")
lines = file.read().split('\n')
for line in lines:
    print(line.split(' ')[0])
file.close()
```

This will give the following output:

```
Janitors
Programers
Secretaries
```